# Prove that $\; U\setminus A = U \iff A=\emptyset\; $ where $U$ is the universe (False proof of the opposite).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, fake-proofs

I think I might have made a false proof for the following problem but I can´t seem to find where the flaw is.

---

Prove that  $\displaystyle \; U\setminus A = U \iff A=\emptyset\; $ where $U$ is the universe.

My atempt

$$U\setminus A=U\iff A=\emptyset\tag{1}$$
$$\iff [(x\notin A\iff x\in U)\iff A=\emptyset]\tag{2}$$
$$\iff [(x\notin A\iff True)\iff A=\emptyset]\tag{3}$$
(this is clearly true since the $\emptyset$ is a set such that $x\notin\emptyset\iff True$ (Thus $A=\emptyset$). But, what I want to achive is arrive at the conlsuion that (1) is equivalent to $True$ using nothing but algebraic manipulation)
$$\iff [(x\in A\lor True)\land (x\notin A\lor False)\iff A=\emptyset]\tag{4}$$
$$\iff [x\notin A\iff A=\emptyset]\tag{5}$$
$$\iff[x\notin A\iff (x\in A\iff x\in\emptyset)]\tag{6}$$
$$\iff [x\notin A\iff (x\in A\iff False]\tag{7}$$
$$\iff [x\in A\iff (x\notin A\lor False)\land(x\in A\lor True)]\tag{8}$$
$$\iff [x\in A\iff x\notin A\land True]\tag{9}$$
$$\iff [x\in A \iff x\notin A]\tag{10}$$
$$\iff False\tag{11}$$
$$\therefore (U\setminus A=U\iff A=\emptyset)\iff False\tag{12}$$

I proved the oposite of what I'm meant to prove.
Where did I go wrong?

(please correct tags if wrong).

Comment: In the last displayed block of 9 lines, the left side of $\iff$ went from $x\notin A$ at line 4 to $x\in A$ at line 5.

Comment: Beware of proofs by blind "algebraic manipulation"... Do bear in mind, also, that it is generally considered bad style to *start* writing a proof by writing *on the first line* the statement that **is to be proved**.

Comment: @RandomUser You used that tautology several times, but it has nothing to do with the error on the **left side** that I pointed out.

Comment: @AndreasBlass , my bad, I was editing the comment as you responded. The tautology I wanted to mention is the following: $(p\lor True)\land (\lnot p\lor False) \iff \lnot p$. In this case, $p$ stands for $x\in A$.

Comment: @RandomUser Still true and still irrelevant. The 4th and 5th lines have equivalent things on the right side of $\iff$  and very inequivalent things on the left.

Comment: @AndreasBlass , is it not the case that the LHS of 4 is equivalent to the LHS of 5 due to $$(p\lor True)\land (\lnot p\lor False) \iff \lnot p$$
In other words
$$(x\in A\lor True)\land (x\notin A\lor False) \iff x\notin A$$
I'm so sorry, Im sure this come out a trolling but i genuinly don't see it :(

Comment: @RandomUser Now I see your problem: My original comment was about the 4th and 5th lines **in the last displayed block of 9 lines**; since then, you've added line numbers to 12 lines, not just the 9. The 4th and 5th of the 9 are now numbered (7) and (8). Look at their left sides.

Comment: @AndreasBlass , omg I'm so dumb. Now I see it thank you very much for putting up with my shit my dude. You have no idea hom many times I retried the proof lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple.

If $a \in A$ then $a \not \in U\setminus A$.  But *everything* is in $U$.

So:  If $A$ is not empty. Then there exists an $a\in A\subset U$.  So $a \not \in U\setminus A$ while $a \in U$.  So $U \ne U\setminus A$.

And if $A=\emptyset$ then $U\setminus A=U\setminus \emptyset =U$.

....

Or if you don't want to do contrapositive proof or want more detail as to why $K \setminus \emptyset = K$ always:

Suppose $U\setminus A = U$. Then for any $a \in A$ then $a\not \in U\setminus A$ and $a\not \in U$. But *everything* is in $U$ so there can not be any $a\in A$.   So $A$ is empty.

Suppose $A=\emptyset$.  Then if $U\setminus A = \{x\in U|x \not \in \emptyset\}=\{x\in U\}\cap \{x\not \in \emptyset\}=U\cap \emptyset^c$.  But as $\forall x; x\not \in \emptyset$ we have $\emptyset^c = U$. so if $A=\emptyset$ then $U\setminus A = U\setminus \emptyset = U \cap \emptyset^c = U\cap U = U$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why does my logic says otherwise then? I know it's flawed but I can't find why.

Comment: I couldn't read your proof.  You seemed to sprinkle $\iff$s as though they were semi-colons and had nothing to do with conditions or logic conclusions, so the whole proof read as isolated and ultimately unrelated clauses.  I had no idea which clauses were stand alone facts and which ones were conditions nor which ones were logic statements.

Comment: $$p$$
$$\iff q$$
Just means that $p$ is equivalent to $q$ much the same way one would use 
$$a$$
$$=b$$
to indicate that $a=b$ when $a$ is described by too many symbols. I didn't know it wasn't standard notation, I'm sorry. What other notation would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the assertion that "$U$ is the universe" implies that $A\subseteq U$. Second, using the definition of set complement, note that $A=\emptyset$ implies that $U\setminus A=U$, and $U\setminus A\subseteq U$. 
So, all you need to prove is that $A\neq\emptyset$ implies that $U\setminus A \not\supseteq U$. But if $A\neq\emptyset$, there must be some $B\in A\subseteq U$, and so $B\not\in U\setminus A$.